# Model CNN Computer Vision (Pizza VS Steak) pretty much just guesses

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

```
# Load images and split them into batches
images_train = Images(
    images_dir_train,
    image_size = (224, 224),
    batch_size = 32
)
 
images_test = Images(
    images_dir_test,
    image_size = (224, 224),
    batch_size = 32
)
 
model_augmented = tf.keras.Sequential()
model_augmented.add(tf.keras.Input(shape = (224, 224, 3)))
model_augmented.add(layers.Rescaling(1.0/255))
# model_augmented.add(layers.RandomFlip("horizontal_and_vertical"))
# model_augmented.add(layers.RandomRotation(0.1))
model_augmented.add(layers.Conv2D(filters = 10, kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu'))
model_augmented.add(layers.Conv2D(filters = 10, kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu'))
model_augmented.add(layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size = 2, padding = 'valid'))
model_augmented.add(layers.Conv2D(filters = 10, kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu'))
model_augmented.add(layers.Conv2D(filters = 10, kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu'))
model_augmented.add(layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size = 2))
model_augmented.add(layers.Flatten())
model_augmented.add(layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
 
model_augmented.compile(
    loss = 'binary_crossentropy', 
    optimizer = 'adam', 
    metrics = ['accuracy']
)
 
history_augmented = model_augmented.fit(
    images_train, 
    validation_data = images_test, 
    epochs = 7
)
 
model_augmented.summary()
```

Guess what? I got 88.7 accuracies on training data and 85 on validation data, now this is my function for loading and preparing an image, I deleted rescaling since it does not make sense for my model, rescaling layer is included in the model:

```
def load_and_prep_image(filename, img_shape=224):
    '''
    Reads an image from filename, turns it into tensor and rehspaes it to (img_shape, img_shape, color_channels)
    '''
    # Read the image
    img = tf.keras.utils.load_img(filename, target_size=(img_shape, img_shape))
    # Convert image to tensor
    img_array = tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(img)
    # Create a batch
    img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0)
    return img_array
```

When using this function on pizza/steak images:

```
pizza = load_and_prep_image("DataSets/prediction_data/pizza-vegetarienne.jpg")
steak = load_and_prep_image("DataSets/prediction_data/steak.jpg")
margherita = load_and_prep_image("DataSets/prediction_data/margherita.jpg")
other_steak = load_and_prep_image("DataSets/prediction_data/other_steak.jpg")
steakA = load_and_prep_image("DataSets/prediction_data/steakA.jpg")
steakB = load_and_prep_image("DataSets/prediction_data/steakB.jpg")
pred_pizza = model.predict(pizza)
pred_margherita = model.predict(margherita)
pred_steak = model.predict(steak)
pred_other_steak = model.predict(other_steak)
pred_steakA = model.predict(steakA)
pred_steakB = model.predict(steakB)
pred_pizza = images_train.class_names[int(tf.round(pred_pizza))]
print('PIZZA ', pred_pizza)
pred_margherita = images_train.class_names[int(tf.round(pred_margherita))]
print('PIZZA ', pred_margherita)
pred_steak = images_train.class_names[int(tf.round(pred_steak))]
print('STEAK ', pred_steak)
pred_other_steak = images_train.class_names[int(tf.round(pred_other_steak))]
print('STEAK ', pred_other_steak)
pred_steakA = images_train.class_names[int(tf.round(pred_steakA))]
print('STEAK ', pred_steakA)
pred_steakB = images_train.class_names[int(tf.round(pred_steakB))]
print('STEAK ', pred_steakB)`
```

I get the following output:

```
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 50ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 46ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 48ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 44ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 41ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 43ms/step
PIZZA  steak
PIZZA  pizza
STEAK  pizza
STEAK  steak
STEAK  steak
STEAK  pizza
```

That is like 50% accuracy, actually, it is guessing. What am I doing wrong? The model was trained on this dataset: https://storage.googleapis.com/ztm_tf_course/food_vision/pizza_steak.zip

I tried changing hyperparameters, reducing the number of layers, and even pre-processing data in different ways. Nothing helps.

Comment: Share some model metrics with us if you can. Like training/validation accuracy, ROC curve, etc. This can help us determine if the model itself is bad, or something in your prediction process

Comment: Are the 6 images that you test with part of `images_test`, or a separat batch of images? If they are part of `images_test`, and depending on the size of `images_test`, it could just be bad luck with these 6 samples. Can you test with other, or more, samples?